# How to make text inside UIButton absolute center both verticaly and horizontaly

Tags: ios

[image]

I am trying to re-implement iOS's calculator but I could not get the `+` operator inside the UIButton absolute center.

Comment: By default, the text of the UIButton would be aligned in the center both horizontally & vertically.

Comment: So the only way I can achive this is to change the vertical position of the text?

Comment: YES, make sure the button is in center to parent view both horizontally & vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the effect I want via change the title insets via Interface Builder.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is fine unless the size changes on different form factors.